# lightning_fabric.utilities.exceptions.MisconfigurationException: You requested gpu: [0, 1, 2] But your machine only has: [0]

Tags: gpu

lightning_fabric.utilities.exceptions.MisconfigurationException: You requested gpu: [0, 1, 2]
But your machine only has: [0]
I have three GPUs available, but it tells me only one can be used.

I checked the GPU status, and there is no problem with it.